# "react-native run-android" gives an error - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. I can run the simulator but the app does not launch

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been searching for solutions for this and I cant seem to find any. Keep in mind, I am new to this and Just want to get my first app started and get more experience with mobile app dev.
I have no clue or idea on how to solve this, tried to delete build directory and build again, tried gradlew clean, everything on every other forum. Please help
Here is the whole error after i type : react-native run-android

> C:\Windows\System32\tester>react-native run-android info Running
>   jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using
>   "--no-jetifier" flag. Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify.
>   Using 8 workers... info Starting JS server... info Launching
>   emulator... info Successfully launched emulator. info Installing the
>   app... Downloading
>   https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
>   .........10%..........20%..........30%..........40%.........50%..........60%..........70%..........80%.........90%..........100%
>
> Welcome to Gradle 6.5!
>
> Here are the highlights of this release:
>    - Experimental file-system watching
>    - Improved version ordering
>    - New samples
>
> For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/release-notes.html
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>   17 actionable tasks: 17 executed
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Multiple task action failures occurred:
>   >     A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
>   development environment set up:
>   https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose
>   flag for more details. Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat
>   app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > Multiple task action failures occurred:
>   >     A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
>   >
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     Android resource compilation failed
>   >         AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\tester\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug:
>   >     error: directory does not exist.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s
>
> ```
> at makeError (C:\Windows\System32\tester\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
> at C:\Windows\System32\tester\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Windows\System32\tester\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (C:\Windows\System32\tester\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
> ```

Comment: you need to show your code

Comment: there is no current code, this is a new project and I am trying to get the simulator to run properly.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the gradle version? Try 6.2, it works for me.